# data on laravel got retrieve 2 times

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-blade

Hello so I have system that showing comment data per post in admin dashboard but I got problem here, So I already showing the data in dashboard but my comment data got retrieve 2 times and I don't know why

here is my function in controller

```
public function getCommentPost($id){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $compalls = $user->posts;
    foreach ($compalls as $key => $value) {
        $compalls[$key]->comment_all = Idea::where('id_post', $id)->get();
    }
    return view('admin.comment_all', compact('compalls'));
}
```

this is the return image
[image]

hope you guys can help me thanks

Ok I add my code in view it simple look like this

```
foreach ($compalls as $compall)
    <tr>
        @foreach ($compall->coment_all as $coment)
            <td>{{ $coment->id_user }}</td>
            <td>{{ $coment->title }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

here is my model on Post.php

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Comment: We need to see your relation stretcher & view. Otherwise, we can't understand.

Comment: ok i've already edit it