# How to get 3 conditions in laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, count, controller, conditional-statements

guys so I want to get 3 conditions in controller Laravel, So I build a post with the comment system. My comment has 3 conditions, from default condition it will get `value = 0`, when is approved it will get `value = 1`, when it's denied it will give `value = 2`. I want to get 3 conditions to count how many it is because I want to build another value like `value = 3` or 4 or 5 for another condition so I won't use get all.

Here is my comment controller function code

```
private function getCountComment()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $comcount = $user->competitions;
    foreach ($comcount as $key => $value) {
        $count = Comment::where('id_post', $value->id)
                        ->where('is_accepted', '=', 0 AND 1 AND 3)
                        ->count();
        $comcount[$key]->comment_to_count = $count;
    }
    return $comcount;
}
```

I try that code but only get the first condition `is_accepted = 0`.

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Look up whereIn(). You pass an array of possible values as the second parameter. IE: ->whereIn('is_accepted', [0, 1, 3])

Comment: Logically it'd be `0 OR 1 OR 3` not and.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
private function getCountComment(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $comcount = $user->competitions;
    foreach ($comcount as $key => $value) {
        $comcount[$key]->comment_to_count = Comment::where('id_post', $value->id)->whereIn('is_accepted', [0,1,3])->count();
    }
    return $comcount;
}
```

or you can

```
Comment::where('id_post', $value->id)->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('is_accepted', '=', 0)
        ->orWhere('is_accepted', '=', 1)
        ->orWhere('is_accepted', '=', 3)
})->count();
```

Comment: thanks bro, can u help me in another case why my data got retrieve 2 times in another question you can check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436032/data-on-laravel-got-retrieve-2-times. really appreciate it